# Passing this as a parameter to a function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass the this keyword down to another function then use it as the selector to style the css of the paragraph. I know i could do it without overcomplicating it like this, but I was just wondering was it possible to do it this way.

```
 $("#test").click(function(){

 testFunction(this.id)

  });


  function(object)
  {
 $(object).css({'background-color': 'red'});

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you're looking for...

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    testFunction(this);
});


function testFunction(object) {
    $(object).css({'background-color': 'red'});
}
```

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/hf43Z/)**

Answer (score 4):

What you have will work, you are just missing the `#` from the selector, as this is not included in the `id` property of the object:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    testFunction(this.id)
});

function testFunction(object) {
    $('#' + object).css({ 'background-color': 'red' });
}
```

However a better solution is to give the function as a reference for the click handler, meaning the `this` keyword is a reference to the clicked element, saving the need for any ugly concatenation of selectors:

```
$("#test").click(testFunction);

function testFunction() {
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'red' });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Others answer are correct.

However, As you are not performing any operation in event handler.

Why not simply use testFunction function as event handler? then you can directly use `this`

```
 $("#test").click(testFunction);

 function testFunction() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'red'
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it as simple

```
$("#test").click(function(){

    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

});
```